# Unable to edit custom post type, editor crashes. What to do?

Tags: block-editor, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type, which also has a custom taxonomy. These have been defined via ACF.

Editing posts of this custom post type results in the Wordpress editor crashing. This seems to happen when the custom taxonomy 'block' is about to load in the sidebar. That the crash is connected to the custom taxonomy is likely, as when I disconnect the custom taxonomy from this custom post type, the editor no longer crashes.

Perhaps relevant, is that the taxonomy has the same slug as the name of a custom field for this custom post type (the reason being that I'm converting the custom field values to the custom taxonomy).

When the editor crashes, I see a notification that says "The editor encountered an unexpected error", and gives me a button that lets me copy the error. Here's an example of that:

```
@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/editor.min.js:12:97164
__unstableMarkListeningStores@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js:2:22512
l@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js:9:1951
@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js:9:2427
Je@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/data.min.js:9:2637
Si@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/editor.min.js:12:96967
wt@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js:10:47638
js@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js:10:120586
wl@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js:10:88661
bl@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js:10:88589
yl@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js:10:88452
il@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js:10:85276
fl@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js:10:85663
Nn@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js:10:32475
@https://c0.wp.com/c/6.4.3/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js:10:83228
```

How do I even begin to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I completed the migration from custom field to custom taxonomy, and removed the custom field, I was able to edit the custom post types again.

So, it appears that you can not have a custom field with a name identical to a custom taxonomy slug.